# Collapsed field in Django Admin's change view

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin

The table `Content` has a field `compressed_string` that stores a very long string in the compressed form. This is what I have to display the original decompressed string in the Django Admin's change view:

```py
class ContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (
        [f.name for f in Content._meta.fields 
                if f.name not in ['compressed_string']] + 
        ['original_string'])
    readonly_fields = ['original_string']
    list_display = [f.name for f in Content._meta.fields]

    def original_string(self, obj):
        return pickle.loads(brotli.decompress(obj.compressed_string))
```

I would like `original_string` to be displayed collapsed, with the possibility to expand and view the whole string. How can I accomplish this?